# If defallt value of "cobra.Command BoolVarP" is "true", it is always "true"

Tags: go, go-cobra

my code

```
    var require bool
    
    cmd.Flags().BoolVarP(&require, "require", "r", true,
        "default: true.")
```

If default value is "true", weather I add "-r" or not, "require" is always "true". But if default value is "false", it works well.

Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the default value of a boolean flag is true, then not passing that flag and  just passing `-r` or `--require` will result in `true`. To set it to false, use `--require=false`.

Comment: Thanks，you are right. But I think it is not reasonable. If default value is `false`, I do not need to use `=true`. And in java, bose case works well.

Comment: Default is used if the flag is not given. For boolean flags, `--required` and `--required=true` mean the same thing. If you set the default to true, `--required=false` or `-r=false` are the only ways to set it back to false. How else would you expect to do it?

Comment: Like in java, default value is `true`, if I use `-r`, value will be `false`. In another  way, if use `-r`, value reversal.

Comment: Note that `-r` is the same thing as `--required`.